# Reading in .csv with irregular row formats

Tags: r, csv

I've been given a bunch of .csv files to read into R. Unfortunately they are formatted very poorly. The formatting goes something like this from the top row down:

1. Header
2. Empty row
3. Data title
4. 5 rows of data
5. Empty row
6. Another data title
7. 5 more rows of data
8. And then the pattern repeats

Here is something that could be pasted into a text file and saved as a .csv that illustrates this issue:

```
"Parameter
",Value,Category
 , , 
Class1, , 
Blue,50,Bright
Green,0.10,Bright
Purple,0.050,Bright
Yellow,0.50,Bright
White,0.20,Bright
 , , 
Class2, , 
Blue,50,Dull
Green,0.10,Dull
Purple,0.050,Dull
Yellow,2.0,Dull
White,0.20,Dull
```

My question is can I use R to remove the empty rows and the data title row so that the .csv reads in correctly without those pesky odd rows messing up the import?

I don't think I can add a .csv directly a question but I apologize for adding an extra step here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

does this solves your problem?

```
na.omit(read.table(your_csv, skip=3, sep=","))
```

or with `read.csv`:

```
na.omit(read.csv(your_csv, skip=3, header=FALSE))
```

We skip the first three lines, as some of them do not have 3 columns. The first line actually read by `read.*`, the 4th, has three columns like all others rows. We then remove any line containing at least one `NA` since blank cells in your `csv` were turned into `NA`s.

Note that if the first lines would have been (likely more properly) formatted like that:

```
Parameter,Value,Category
 , , 
Class1, , 
Blue,50,Bright
```

then `na.omit(read.csv(your_csv))` would have done the job *and* preserved the header.

Comment: It does, though I do not know why.

Comment: I have detailed the 'why', and shortened the 'how'. is there something unclear now?